# How can I find duplicate records from array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to find duplicate records from a given array. I have tried the following function, but it did not work as expected, later I come to know I was comparing the same record with itself. I have written the following function.

```
identifyDupliateRecords(verifiedRecordsAll) {
    let duplicateRecords : any;
    if(verifiedRecordsAll.length > 1){
      const tempDuplicateRecords = []
      this.verifiedRecordsAll.forEach((record)=> {
        if(verifiedRecordsAll.Some === verifiedRecordsAll.Some ||
          verifiedRecordsAll.Gum === verifiedRecordsAll.Gum ||
          verifiedRecordsAll.Thing === verifiedRecordsAll.Thing) {
          tempDuplicateRecords.push(record);
          duplicateRecords = tempDuplicateRecords
        }
      })
    }
    return duplicateRecords
  }
```

For finding duplicate records I need to have such a condition that if Some or Gum or Thing property of one record should match the value of another record in the same array, then it should be stored as a duplicate.
I am new to JS and cannot think of any other solution.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use this link. for more information https://flexiple.com/find-duplicates-javascript-array/

Comment: you could use lodash

Comment: @user3929590 Do you have any site where I can refer how to work upon it?

Answer (score 1):

this.verifiedRecordsAll=[] --Array need to add

this.verifiedRecordsAll =this.verifiedRecordsAll.filter((element, i) => i ===  this.verifiedRecordsAll.indexOf(element))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

const yourArray=[]
let duplicatedRecords=[]

```
for(let k=0;k<array.length;k++){
   for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     if(k!==i&&array[k]===array[i]){
        duplicatedRecords.push(array[k])
     }
  } 
}
duplicatedRecords= [...new Set(duplicatedRecords)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following function declared here as `findDuplicates`, returns an array with the duplicate elements/records of the array passed in as an argument.

```js
const findDuplicates = myArray => {
  return myArray.filter((element, index, array) => {
    return array.indexOf(element) !== index;
  });
};

console.log(findDuplicates([8, 6, 0, 2, 5, 9, 6, 5])); // Returns: [6, 5]
```

**Explanation:**
The `.filter(callback)` built-in array method filters elements for which the callback argument returns true. This callback relies on `.indexOf(element)`, another built-in array method that returns the first index that holds the element; all duplicate elements will have "non-first" indexes.